sqlite db not being created in RUN instruction during image build (python/pdm)
What I'm trying to do is for a new sqlite db file to be created when spinning up a container. But the db files doesn't get created for some reason. When I run the file inside the container normally: pdm run src/db_setup.py it works fine and the file is created.
So why doesn't the RUN pdm run -v src/db_setup.py step do this?
I run the container with docker run --name de_pdm_container -p 8080:8080 -dt -v .:/app de_pdm
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-bookworm

WORKDIR /app

# install PDM
RUN pip install -U pdm
# disable update check
ENV PDM_CHECK_UPDATE=false

COPY pdm.lock pyproject.toml ./
RUN pdm install

COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./tests ./tests
COPY .devcontainer .devcontainer

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
RUN pdm run -v src/db_setup.py

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["pdm", "run", "uvicorn", "src.de_pdm.__init__:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080", "--reload"]

db_setup.py
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cursor = con.cursor()

con.set_trace_callback(print)

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb;")
con.commit()
cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE tb(
            country VARCHAR(50),
            country_code VARCHAR(2),
            year INT,
            estimated_population_number INT,
            estimated_prevalence INT
        );
""")
con.commit()
con.close()


Do you have any volume mappings when you run the container?

Building from Dockerfile doesn't involve volume mappings. Presumably so this kind of thing doesn't happen.

@HansKilian yes, I use docker run --name de_pdm_container -p 8080:8080 -dt -v .:/app de_pdm. I'll add it to my question

If you're mounting a volume over /app in the container, it hides almost everything the Dockerfile does.  I'd recommend removing that -v option, so that you're using what's built into the image.  (Note that persisting the SQLite file will be a problem, and typical practice is to use a separate database container.)

@DavidMaze not necessarily looking for it to persist, since I do want it to be newly created upon each new creation. Maybe I'll look into compose and just add a basic mysql server or something

It would be safer to use a full path for the DB in your Python script. You cannot always be sure what the current relative path will be. Maybe the DB file was indeed created, but not where you expect.
